# Error in my reasoning to prove a bounded convergence theorem for the Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was trying to prove this fact:

If $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions from $[0;1]\to[0;1]$ such that $f_n(x)\to0\ \forall x\in[0;1]$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=0$.

While trying to prove this, I reached the result that convergence is uniform, which sounds absurd. I'd like to see the error in my reasoning and see a proof of this fact (that doesn't depend on measure theory):

Fix $\varepsilon$

Let $E_n=\{x\in[0;1] / f_n(x)>\varepsilon\}$

Let $A_k=\cup_k^\infty E_n$.

Finally, let $A=\cap_1^\infty \overline{A_k}$.

There are two cases:

1) $A=\emptyset$. Then, since each $\overline{A_k}$ is compact and $\overline{A_{k+1}}\subset\overline{A_k}$ then $A_K$ is empty for some $A_K$. Thus, $E_n=\emptyset\ \forall n>K$. Thus, convergence is uniform.

2) $A\neq\emptyset$. Then, some $x$ belongs to $\overline{A_k}\forall k$. Then, $f_n(x)\geq\varepsilon\ \forall n_i$ and $n_i$ an infinite subsequence of the integers which means that $f_n(x)$ doesn't converge to $0$.

I suspect that my error is in the last statement but I am not sure why and I have struggled to find a proof of the fact but I didn't reach anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be that convergence is uniform, actually. You have a strong assumption of uniform boundedness of the sequence: $0\le f_n(x)\le 1$. I have still not checked your proof, though.

Comment: I doubted that convergence is uniform since I haven't come upon such a theorem before, and Rudin asked to prove that the integral converges whereas he could have asked to prove uniform convergence if so was the case. I'll wait for a definite answer though.

Comment: Also, it does not seem that I have used uniform boundedness.

Comment: Yes. Indeed, your proposed proof must be wrong, as the sequence $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} nx, & 0\le x\le \frac1n \\ -n\left( x-\frac2n\right), & \frac1n \le x \le \frac2n \\ 0, & \frac2n\le x\le 1 \end{cases}$$ satisfies the assumptions $f_n\colon [0, 1]\to [0, 1]$, converges to $0$ pointwise but $\|f_n\|_\infty= 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Hmm. I'd really appreciate it if you could point out where I strayed in my reasoning and if you could provide a proof of the fact posed.

Comment: You used the false fact that $\overline{A_k}=\cup_{n=k}^\infty \overline{E_n}$. The closure of an infinite union needs not be the union of the closures. So in point 2, you are right that there exists $x\in$ some $\overline{A_k}$. But you cannot infer that $f_n(x)\ge \epsilon$.

Comment: Hmm, that's right. Now that you mention it, it is obvious that the fact is false by taking $\mathbb{Q}=\cup_{1}^\infty \{r_i\}$ where $r_i$ is the $i$th rational number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example to make Giuseppe Negro's comment explicit.

Let $\{a_n\}\subset[0,1]$ be a strictly decreasing sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Let $f_n\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function defined by $f_n(x)=0$ on $[0,a_{n+1}]\cup[a_n,1]$, $f(a_{n+1}+a_n)/2=1$, $f_n$ linear on $[a_{n+1},a_{n+1}+a_n)/2]$ and $[(a_{n+1}+a_n)/2,a_n]$. $E_n$ is an open interval centered at $(a_{n+1}+a_n)/2$ of length $(1-\epsilon)(a_{n+1}-a_n)$. $\overline A_k$ is the union of the closed intervals $\overline E_N$ and $\{0\}$, and $A=\{0\}$. However, $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$.

You can find an elementary proof of the result in [this paper by Nadish de Silva](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/000298910X523407?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Answer (score 0):

As GiuseppeNegro said, you can not choose the index "$n$" in your argument "$f_n(x) \geq \epsilon$".

Because $x\in \overline{\cup_{n=k}^\infty E_n} = \overline{A_k}$, this does not imply $x\in \overline{E_N}$ for some $N \geq k.$ And you need $x\in \overline{E_N}$ in order to conclude $f_N(x) \geq \epsilon$.

For counter example of the topological argument, $\overline{\cup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \{q\}}$ and $\cup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \overline {\{q\}}$.